# scan all directories and files by order php

Tags: php, scandir

I spend(waste) 2 days for this awful code (that may have few errors)

```
$diretc [] = ('../documentos');
    $txt = "";

    function getDirContents($diret){
        for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($diret) ; $i++) { 
            $dir = $diret[$i];
            if(is_dir($dir)){ //lee si es un directorio
                $GLOBALS['txt'] .= '<ul>'.$dir;
                while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                    if (is_dir($archivo)) {
                        $directorios[] = $archivo;
                    }
                    else if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
                        $GLOBALS['txt'] .= '<li>'.$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$archivo.'</li>';
                    }
                }
                $GLOBALS['txt'] .='</ul>';
            }
        }
        if (sizeof($directorios) > 0) {
            getDirContents($directorios);
        }
        return $txt;    
    }





echo getDirContents($diretc);
```

I tried to list each directories  with their files from my path **documentos**  I want all that by order, like a file manager,like a tree like [this](https://twittstrap.com/angular-filemanager)

Comment: So exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: replace every `$GLOBALS['txt']` with `$txt`. `$diret` should be a string not an array

Comment: @Ini & Dagon: but then don't forget to put `global $txt;` in your function.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no global needed

Comment: @Ini: Perhaps try to learn PHP with some code that is simpler? Get the basics under control, and then try something a little bit harder? Two days for the code you show is terrible... I feel for you. This is not good for your mood.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to help. Please try the following code.

```
function listDir($path, $recursive = false) {
    $recursive = ( $recursive === true );
    $invalidPaths = array( '.', '..' );
    $valid = is_dir($path);
    if ($valid !== true) {
        return array();
    }
    $array = array();
    foreach(scandir($path) as $file) {
        // Check for invalid paths
        $invalid = in_array( $file, $invalidPaths );
        if ($invalid === true) {
            continue;
        }
        // Format and add file
        $filename = "$path/$file";
        array_push($array, $filename);

        // Check for read dir recursive
        $isDirectory = is_dir($file);
        if ($isDirectory && !$recursive) {
            continue;
        }

        // Add itens
        $subDirArray = listDir($filename, $recursive);
        $array = array_merge($array, $subDirArray);
    }
    return $array;
}

$path = '../documentos';
$pathList = listDir($path, true);
foreach($pathList as $item) {
    echo "<pre>$item</pre>";
}
```